# What is the C# Linq equivalent to VB.Net Linq Group Join and Into keywords?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I am trying to rewrite an old vb.net app in C#. I have come across this linq code that I need to convert:

```
 (From wn In dtx.WebQueryGroupNames Group Join _
                    wqg In dtx.WebQueryGroups On wn.QueryGroupNameKey Equals wqg.QueryGroupNameKey _
                    Into Group _
                    From p In Group.DefaultIfEmpty() _
                    Select wn _
                    Where Not (From x In dtx.WebQueryGroups Where x.QueryKey = queryKey Select x.QueryGroupNameKey).Contains(wn.QueryGroupNameKey)).Distinct.ToList
```

What I have so far is:

```
 (from wn in dtx.WebQueryGroupNames Group join  
        wqg in dtx.WebQueryGroups on wn.QueryGroupNameKey equals wqg.QueryGroupNameKey 
        Into Group 
        from p in Group.DefaultIfEmpty() 
        select wn 
        where !(from x in dtx.WebQueryGroups where x.QueryKey = queryKey select x.QueryGroupNameKey).Contains(wn.QueryGroupNameKey)).Distinct();
```

I can't seem to find any information on the Group and Into keywords as it translates to C#. I think I am missing a key point that makes this query make sense.

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397941.aspx is another good resource (if you know the logical name of what you're trying to do, not necessarily just the VB.NET keywords for it).

Comment: @Rodrigo I use that site all the time and it is an excellent resource; however, it does not help me convert VB.Net code to C# when I am not sure what the original developer was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `Group Join` translates into a plan `join` with an `into` clause. Try this

```
 (from wn in dtx.WebQueryGroupNames join  
        wqg in dtx.WebQueryGroups on wn.QueryGroupNameKey equals wqg.QueryGroupNameKey 
        into g
        from p in g.DefaultIfEmpty() 
        select wn 
        where !(from x in dtx.WebQueryGroups where x.QueryKey = queryKey select x.QueryGroupNameKey).Contains(wn.QueryGroupNameKey)).Distinct();
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The term you're looking for is [Group By](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx).

```
var queryLastNames =
    from student in students
    group student by student.LastName into newGroup
    orderby newGroup.Key
    select newGroup;
```